# Reversing the words

Tags: c#

This is the question:

"Write a program that reverses the words in a given sentence without changing punctuation and spaces. For example: "C# is not C++ and PHP is not Delphi" à "Delphi not is PHP and C++ not is C#"."

This is the hint:
"Another interesting approach is to split the input text by punctuation marks between words, in order to get just the words of the text and then split by the letters to get the punctuation marks of the text. Thus, given a list of words and a list of punctuation marks between them, you can easily reverse the words, preserving the punctuation marks."

This is my code so far:

```
public static string ReverseWords(string str)
    {
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        string[] words = str.Split('.', ' ');
        char[] x = str.ToCharArray();

        string[] punctuation = str.Split(str.ToCharArray());

        for(int position = words.Length - 1; position >= 0; position--)
        {
            answer.Append(words[position]);
            answer.Append(' ');
        }

        return answer.ToString();
    }
```

My problem is that the way i solved is specific to the example given. If there are other delimiters, the code doesn't work correctly. 
So how can I generalize the algorithm to work with any delimiter using the given hint ?!

Comment: It's a terrible hint actually. It's much easier to read the string from the end, accumulate a word, reverse it and write to a string builder.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Regex?

Comment: @zerkms Ya that way was included. Hence why this hint starts with "Another". But since I'm capable of implementing (i think :)), I opted for this more "interesting" approach. I like that I get to use a string method as I want to get familiar with them.

Comment: @ToddRichardson No. Only because I did not learn Regex yet :)

Comment: @Mustafa: "Ya that way was included". It's not - your solution implies it's a space as a separator. Mine - just reads characters one by one, without any assumptions.

Comment: @zerkms I mean included as a hint. Which I chose to ignore. My solution's problem is that it cannot handle other delimiters.

Comment: @Mustafa: just follow my algorithm - it's a naive implementation.

Comment: @zerkms wouldn't you still need to know a delimiter to "accumulate a word"?

Comment: @aw04: everything that is not a word is a delimiter. So - words are accumulated and reversed, delimiters - just written through.

Comment: If you need the position of punctuation as well, assuming words will vary of course in length, you need to discover which words they fall inbetween in terms of the word count (i.e.- a comma comes between the third and fourth word in the sentence). That adds complexity but basically this is something you can test on the original string without having to make many changes to your existing code. As far as other delimiters just add them to your str.Split() call (or create a char array with the ones you need and put that in there instead). Good luck :)

Comment: @Mustafa What sample input are you having trouble with? and what delimiters do you want to have?

Comment: And zerkms' solution will most definitely work, although you still need to keep track of where the punctuation lies to replace it in the new string. But that might actually be easier with his suggested method (but depending on your instructor, I find some get picky about non-OOP solutions in an OOP language, just depends).

Comment: Umm .. This is embarresing but I can't implement zerkms solution :). Except for the part of just reversing the input str of course. But I can't form the word for the backward letters

Comment: What he is suggesting is copying characters backwards until you hit a delimiter, and then reversing the order of those characters. But your method will also work, you need to add more delimiters and you need to look at str and find what words each punctuation falls between in terms of order so you can place them back into the new string.

Comment: I also notice you have the char array x, but you never use it. What was your intention for that array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much shorter version of your `Method/Function` would look like this:

```
public static string ReverseWords(string str)
{       
   return String.Join(" ", str.Split('.', ' ').Reverse()).ToString();
}
```

Comment: This is beautiful to me. And it works for any delimiter. Thanx

Comment: @Mustafa: Nice that it works for you. Happy coding and GOD bless.

Answer (score 0):

"Another interesting approach is to **split the input text by punctuation marks between words**"

You did that here, just need to expand the delimiters to cover other punctuation

```
string[] words = str.Split('.', ' ');
```

You have just '.' and ' ', very simply you need to expand this list to cover all possible punctuation (such as !, ?, etc.)

"in order to get just the words of the text and **then split by the letters to get the punctuation marks of the text**."

Now do the same thing to the original string, but use all possible alphabet characters as the delimiters instead of using punctuation. This will pull out punctuation marks without spaces or letters.

The tricky part is where to put those pesky punctuation marks in the new sentence. My solution is probably not the most elegant solution, but I would count the n spaces before the mark, and place the mark after the n+1 word in the new sentence. Keep in mind this will not in any way guarantee good grammar :)

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with a regular expression

It would look like

```
(\w+|[^\w])
```

The match group would be words or punctuation, then you could just reverse the matches.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here, I think, lies in how you define "word". Is something like `mother-in-law` a single word, or 3 words, separated by hyphens. How about `That's`?

For the purposes of argument, I'm defining word as a sequence of letters and digits.

First, lets define a custom data type to represent our *tokens*: a chunk of text with an associated type (in our case, 'word' or 'non-word'):

```
public enum TokenType
{
  Word    = 1 ,
  NonWord = 2 ,
}

public class Token
{

  public TokenType Type { get ; set ; }
  public string    Text { get ; set ; }

  // This helps in viewing instances in the debugger
  public override string ToString()
  {
    return string.Format( "{0}:{1}" , Type,Text ) ;
  }

}
```

Once we have that, we need a *tokenizer* to split the source text into a sequence of *tokens*:

```
static IEnumerable<Token> Tokenize( string s )
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder() ;
  int i = 0 ;

  while ( i < s.Length )
  {
    // gobble and return a punctuation token, if there is one.
    sb.Length = 0 ;
    while ( i < s.Length && !char.IsLetterOrDigit(s[i]) )
    {
      sb.Append(s[i++]) ;
    }
    if ( sb.Length > 0 ) yield return new Token{ Type = TokenType.NonWord , Text = sb.ToString() , } ;

    // gobble the next word and return it.
    sb.Length = 0 ;
    while ( i < s.Length && char.IsLetterOrDigit( s[i] ) )
    {
      sb.Append( s[i++] ) ;
    }
    if ( sb.Length > 0 ) yield return new Token{ Type = TokenType.Word , Text = sb.ToString() , } ;
  }
}
```

After that, it's all easy:

```
static int Main( string[] argv )
{
  string src = "The quick brown fox, who was named Fred, jumped over a lazy Dog (named Suzy) chasing a squirrel." ;
  List<Token> tokens = new List<Token>( Tokenize( src ) ) ;

  int i = 0 ;
  int j = tokens.Count - 1 ;

  // loop, reversing words as we go.
  while ( i < j )
  {
    Token left  = tokens[i] ;
    Token right = tokens[j] ;

    if ( left.Type  != TokenType.Word ) { ++i ; continue ; }
    if ( right.Type != TokenType.Word ) { --j ; continue ; }

    // at this point, we have two words: swap them
    tokens[i++] = right     ;
    tokens[j--] = left      ;

  }

  // Finally, put everything back together
  string rev = tokens
               .Aggregate( new StringBuilder() , (b,t) => b.Append(t.Text) )
               .ToString()
               ;

  // Et, Voila!
  Console.WriteLine( "src: {0}" , src ) ;
  Console.WriteLine( "rev: {0}" , rev ) ;

  return 0 ;
}
```

**Edited to note:** The above code spits out the following output:

```
src: The quick brown fox, who was named Fred, jumped over a lazy Dog (named Suzy) chasing a squirrel.
rev: squirrel a chasing Suzy, named Dog lazy a, over jumped Fred named was (who fox) brown quick The.
```

**Further edited to note:** If you wanted to use regular expressions, you could use something like this as your tokenizer:

```
static IEnumerable<Token> Tokenize( string s )
{
  Regex rx = new Regex( @"(?<word>\w+)|(?<nonword>\W+)" , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase ) ;
  return rx
         .Matches( s )
         .Cast<Match>()
         .Select( m => new Token {
           Type = m.Groups["word"].Success ? TokenType.Word         : TokenType.NonWord         ,
           Text = m.Groups["word"].Success ? m.Groups["word"].Value : m.Groups["nonword"].Value ,
         }) ;
}
```